# wp_redirect not working inside add_action( ‘wpcf7_after_flamingo’)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Please see below code:

```
function action_wpcf7_after_flamingo( $result ) {
   if($result['contact_form_id'] == 329){
   /** SOME CALCULATIONS HERE **/ 
    $url = ; //Url to payment Checkout
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_after_flamingo', 'action_wpcf7_after_flamingo', 10, 1 );
```

In the above function, I want to do some calculations based on contact form values and then want to redirect the browser to the payment gateway checkout page.

I am able to do some calculations based on contact form values but wp_redirect() is not working. Please share how can I redirect to another URL inside any add_action();

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation line 113:

[Contact Form 7 Flamingo Module](https://gitlab.netisse.fr/msfari/NAP-wordpress/blob/6da1cf23b8514bc72d45edc3eeda53ab80ab3386/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/flamingo.php)

It appears that this action is firing inside of the form submit function.  Meaning, the form has already been submitted and the headers have already been sent.  The key here is headers already sent.  The action 'wpcf7_after_flamingo' comes well after the firing order in WordPress for hooks.  To do a wp_redirect() you should use the hook 'template_redirect' as discussed in the codex:

[Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

So how do you solve it?  According to Contact Form 7 the best thing to do is use a bit of javascript for an event listener:

[Contact Form 7 Documentation](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

So, I believe (* this is 100% un-tested) that the following should work:

1. Add that snippet of javascript to your footer.php file in your theme/child-theme
2. Change the location URL to your url of choice.  You can even include a parameter if you want to watch for something on the page you are redirecting to.
3. Take the wp_redirect() out of the 'wpcf7_after_flamingo' action you have it in

*EDITED:*

[Event Listeners](https://pineco.de/catch-javascript-events-in-contact-form-7/)

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( event.detail.contactFormId == '17' ) {
        console.log(event.detail);
    }
}, false );
```

The key is to open up your console and find out everything that is packed into the ***'event'*** variable passed in.  From there should be easy to make the URL

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I know about  Contact form 7 JS event listeners. But i can't do this work in JS/jQuery. I want following 
1- Id of last inserted form data.
2- Create a Checkout URL using Square Up PHP SDK 

and then redirect to that Checkout URL created in step 2 mentioned above.

Comment: If you know how to return checkout url from 'wpcf7_after_flamingo'  to wpcf7mailsent' eventListener than it will work good for me.

Comment: @OptimumCreative - I'm not going to load up Contact Forms 7 because I am a Gravity Form guy ;) - and I'd also have to load the Flamingo Module.  But, I believe this is what you are looking for.  Edited answer above.

Comment: Ok .. Thank you for your time.. But believe me your approach will not work in my case, as i need to do some calculations and generate a checkout request/Url server side.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take it from you because you are the one that knows what is inside of that 'event' variable.  I venture to say it has everything inside of it you need to do your calculations on the javascript side.  However, if you had to do it server side, I would just open up an AJAX connection and be done with it.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually event variable does not have submission ID and contact form field values. and i need to set last submission ID and contact form filed values to Checkout URL. thats why i can't use a simple ajax approach.

Answer (score 0):

wp_redirect() should not work after page output started. You can do the redirect with javascript:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

Comment: No.. It wont work. I am inside PHP  function. PHP function is accessed using Ajax and i am not able to change Ajax code.. Your approach will not work here. Thank your for your time.